# Changing UITextField Placeholder Color for ALL textfields in appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I know you can change the placeholder text with following code:

```
mailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black])
```

unfortunately, I have a lot of textfields which should look all the same. So its very annoying to copy paste this code above for every textfield.

Today I found out you can change with `appearance()` in appDelegate the appearance of an UIElement if you want it to be always the same. The following code works perfectly fine for labels:

```
UILabel.appearance().textColor = Colors.greyLabel
```

But when I try to do this for textfield placeholders, it does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could just create your own `UITextField` subclass, where on init you set the `attributedPlaceholder` and make sure all of your text fields in your app use your custom subclass rather than `UITextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom class which is subclass of `UITextField` as

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomTextField:UITextField{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setProperties()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setProperties()
    }

    func setProperties(){

        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textAlignment = .left
        textColor = .black
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        borderStyle = .roundedRect
        if let placeholder = self.placeholder {
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green])
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using storyboard then you can assign that custom class to `UITextField`

[image]

And programatically

```
var mailTextField = CustomTextField()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ֿ`appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses` but it’s available up from iOS 9.

Example:

```
UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UITextField.self]).textColor = UIColor.redColor()’
```